# Trying to minimise a function wrt 2 variables for robust portfolio optimisation. How to do this with fmincon?

Tags: matlab, optimization, robust

I am currently involved in a group project where we have to conduct portfolio selection and optimisation. The paper being referenced is given here: (specifically page 5 and 6, equations 7-10)

http://faculty.london.edu/avmiguel/DeMiguel-Nogales-OR.pdf

We are having trouble creating the optimisation problem using M-Portfolios, given below

min (wrt w,m) (1/T) * sum_(rho)*(w'*r_t - m) (Sorry I couldn't get the formatting to work)

s.t. w'e = 1 (just a condition saying that all weights add to 1)

So far, this is what we have attempted:

```
function optPortfolio =  portfoliofminconM(returns,theta)

% Compute the inputs of the mean-variance model
mu = mean(returns)';
sigma = cov(returns);

 % Inputs for the fmincon function
T = 120;
n = length(mu);
w = theta(1:n);
m = theta((n+1):(2*n));
c = 0.01*ones(1,n);
Aeq = ones(1,(2*n));
beq = 1;
lb = zeros(2,n);
ub = ones(2,n);
x0 = ones(n,2) / n; % Start with the equally-weighted portfolio
options = optimset('Algorithm', 'interior-point', ...
    'MaxIter', 1E10, 'MaxFunEvals', 1E10);

% Nested function which is used as the objective function
function objValue = objfunction(w,m)
    cRp = (w'*(returns - (ones(T,1)*m'))';
    objValue = 0;
    for i = 1:T
        if abs(cRp(i)) <= c;
            objValue = objValue + (((cRp(i))^2)/2);
        else
            objValue = objValue + (c*(abs(cRp(i))-(c/2)));
        end
    end
```

The problem starts at our definitions for theta being used as a vector of w and m. We don't know how to use fmincon with 2 variables in the objective function properly. In addition, the value of the objective function is conditional on another value (as shown in the paper) and this needs to be done over a rolling time window of 120 months for a total period of 264 months.(hence the for-loop and if-else)

If any more information is required, I will gladly provide it!

If you can additionally provide an example that deals with a similar problem, can you please link us to it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way you minimize a function of two scalars with fmincon is to write your objective function as a function of a single, two-dimensional vector. For example, you would write `f(x,y) = x.^2 + 2*x*y + y.^2` as `f(x) = x(1)^2 + 2*x(1)*x(2) + x(2)^2`.

More generally, you would write a function of two vectors as a function of a single, large vector. In your case, you could rewrite your objfunction or do a quick hack like:

```
objfunction_for_fmincon = @(x) objfunction(x(1:n), x(n+1:2*n));
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks that helped I think! But we only have a constraint on x(1), but not on x(2)) so when applying the Aeq, beq constraints to satisfy that the sum of weights equals one, it seems to apply them on x(2) as well, which should not happen. How do I restrict it so that Aeq and beq constraints only apply to the first vector column in x? I hope that makes sense. Thank you!